# Letter from CS Lewis to Arthur C. Clarke about Olaf Stapledon/Star Maker: "Sheer devil worship"

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, cs-lewis, olaf-stapledon

I am looking for a letter mentioned in the [Wikipedia page for Olaf Stapledon's *Star Maker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Maker). In this letter from C.S. Lewis to Arthur C. Clarke, Lewis allegedly describes *Star Maker* as "sheer devil worship". The citation says the quote is from *C.S. Lewis: Life, Works, and Legacy*.

Is there a copy of this letter anywhere?

Comment: I would have said "[go buy the book](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=9780275991166)", but $200+ is unconscionably expensive. You could ask your library if they have it.  The book containing C.S. Lewis's letters is a lot cheaper: https://www.amazon.com/Letters-C-S-Lewis/dp/0062643568

Comment: The book [From Narnia to a Space Odyssey: The War of Letters Between Arthur C. Clarke and C. S. Lewis](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?24079) contains at least a mention of [Stapledon's "Star Maker"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/From_Narnia_to_a_Space_Odyssey/ktIfAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=stapledon) but I don't have a copy to see how much of the actual letter is in there.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 26):

In *From Narnia to a Space Odyssey: The War of Letters Between Arthur C. Clarke and C. S. Lewis*, the first *very short* letter from Lewis to Clarke (December 7, 1943), Lewis is responding to Clarke's accusation that Lewis sees all SF as trashy space opera and that Lewis' portrait of Weston is colored by that. Lewis responds:

> I don't of course think that at any moment many scientists are hidding Westons: but I do think (hang it all, I *live* among scientists!) that a point of view not unlike Weston's is on the way. Look at Stapledon (*Star gazer* ends in sheer devil worship), Haldane's *Rosetta Worlds* and Waddington's *Science & Ethics*. I agree Technology is *per se* neutral: but a race devoted to the increase of it own forces & technology with complete indifference to either *does* seem to me a cancer in the universe.
>
> <sub>(*From Narnia to a Space Odyssey*, p. 40; errors in original)</sub>

In a quick skim of the book, I don't see another reference, but I'll go back over it in more detail and add anything relevant.

Comment: Google books finds a reference to "Star Maker" on p.38, but from context that appears to be a letter from Clarke to Lewis.  "sheer devil worship" is hard to mistake, so I'm guessing this is the quote the Wikipedia article is referring to. :)  Stapledon doesn't appear to have written a story called "Star Gazer" or anything with "gaze" in the title.  In fact the only story Stapledon wrote with "Star" in the title is "Star Maker" so it's likely that's an error on Lewis' part.

Comment: does Lewis call it Star Gazer as in the text above or is that just a transcription error?

Comment: @NKCampbell I verified the quote against the non-OCR scan of the book from Google books; the quote is as it appears in the book, except for the [sic] which I probably should remove.

Comment: The opening paragraph of the letter can be found [here](http://yourdailycslewis.blogspot.com/2005/08/lewis-and-clarke.html), along with one extra sentence at the end of the paragraph quoted in *From Narnia to a Space Odyssey*.

Comment: I recently read Stapledon's "Star Maker" and I can see why, from Lewis's perspective he would make that comment. It's a work that dismisses out of hand the absolutist view of an  omnipotent god in favor of hierarchies of alien powers that are capable of creating entire universes. It's a "turtles all the way down" perspective that's not too different from some of the more recent comments from cosmologists.

Comment: @C Teegarden: Very true!  Especially in his Deep Space trilogy, Lewis warns against the worship of the merely big -- which is surely what the worship of super-powerful aliens is. I think he would have been appalled the message Asimov's "The Last Question", while liking the story as a story.